# Why is my POST an undefined array?

Tags: php, html, post

I've been creating an attedance sheet of sorts and I recently ran into this problem:

Every time I attempt to grab a specific POST value from my HTML form, I get an error that reads :
 **Notice: Undefined index: lastN in C:\xampp2\htdocs\weekAttendance.php on line 15**

Now, I have spent a good three days attempting to google/stack the answer and I've tried nearly every solution such as using isset, mysqli_real_escape_string, checking to make sure my HTML form had the correct name attributes, and much more but I am still unsure as to why I am receiving this error. I have three other Posts that work just fine following the method I have used. Can anyone help me?

Here's my relevant HTML:

```
<form action="weekAttendance.php" method="POST">
Select Student Name: 
<select id="lastN" name="lastN">
<option value="" selected> Select a Name from the List Below</option>
<option value="Alvarez">Liana Alvarez</option>
<option value="Barlow">Debra Barlow</option>
<option value="Bester">Anthony Bester</option>
<option value="Delvalle">Madelyn Delvalle</option>
<option value="Flowers">Crystal Flowers</option>
<option value="Hoefner">Peggy Hoefner</option>
<option value="Mingo">Kamika Mingo</option>
<option value="Richards">Deyanira Richards</option>
<option value="Sims">Charles Sims</option>
<option value="Wixom">Jason Wixom</option>
<option value="Pittman">Toniqua Pittman </option>
<option value="Mainer">Sandra Mainer</option>
</select>
<br>
Date: <input type="date" name="daydate">
<br>
Time In: <input type="time" name="inD">
Time Out:<input type="time" name="outD">
<br>
Not listed here? <a href="#">Click here to create a new Student.</a>
<br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

And here is weekAttendance.php:

```
$dDate=date("l", (strtotime($_POST['daydate'])));
$mon;
$tue;
$wed;
$thur;
$fri;
$dayVar;
$timeIN=$_POST['inD'];
$timeOUT=$_POST['outD'];

    if(isset($_POST['lastN'])){
$lastName=$_POST['lastN'];
echo $lastName;
}
$hoursDay;
$weekID;
#$totalHours2= ($mon + $tue + $wed + $thur +$fri)/24)
if ($dDate==="Monday"){
    $mon="Monday";
    $dayVar=$mon;
}
if ($dDate==="Tuesday"){
    $tue="Tue";
    $dayVar=$tue;   
}
if ($dDate==="Wednesday"){
    $wed="Wed";
    $dayVar=$wed;
}
if ($dDate==="Thursday"){
    $thur="Thurs";
    $dayVar=$thur;

}
if ($dDate==="Friday"){
    $fri="Fri";
    $dayVar=$fri;
}

/*$sql="INSERT INTO $dayVar ('$dayVar', first_name2, last_name2,wid)
VALUES($hoursDay','$firstName', '$lastName','$weekId');*/
echo $dayVar." <strong> Time In</strong> " .$timeIN." <strong>Time Out</strong> " .$timeOUT;
```

Comment: Apparently, "lastN" is not in your POST.  It doesn't say "undefined array," it says "undefined index," which means it couldn't find an entry with the key "lastN" in the `_POST` array.

Comment: plus, you have no options other than `<option value="" selected> Select a Name from the List Below</option>` so this tells me you're probably using JS/Ajax and who knows which MySQL API you're using to connect with.

Comment: @Rovery Harvey Not in my post as in not within the post tags or in the HTML? As far as I can see lastN is within post.

Comment: if you're using anything other than `mysql_` functions to connect with, then `$lastName=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastN']);` will fail.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have other options, I just did not include it in my question posting but I will make that edit. I am using MySQL to store the data, the "my_sql_real_escape_string" was one of the solutions I'd found online in relation to post-variables being used in MySQL Inserts

Comment: A value for `lastN` will only appear in your `POST` data if you have actually selected something. If not, `$_POST['lastN']` will not be set at all. Test it with `isset()` before assigning it.

Comment: as per your edit `select id="lastN" name="lastN">` if it's not missing the `<` please add it.

Comment: @HoboSapiens Right, when I try to select an option on my html form and submit, I still receive the same error. I did try isset but the same error occurs

Comment: you're welcome. Now, is your HTML form and PHP/SQL all inside the same file? As per what's been said to use `isset()`, have you tried `if(isset($_POST['lastN'])){ $lastName=$_POST['lastN']; }` ?

Comment: by the way, you have a quote missing for `VALUES($hoursDay'` and the quotes in `INSERT INTO $dayVar ('$dayVar',` are wrong. why are you using that in your query? error checking on the query should be throwing you a syntax error. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, my PHP and SQL are all within the same file, I omitted it at the top, but I have vars for the database and ect.  I tried your suggestion and recieved this error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp2\htdocs\weekAttendance.php on line 15

Comment: you need to replace what I suggested with where you have `$lastName=$_POST['lastN'];` right now. Plus, check the other comment I left above about the VALUES and INSERT...

Comment: @Fred-ii- Currently I just kind of threw that in in preperation for later. It's all commented out. Also the code has been added to my question.

Comment: I posted an answer below to better illustrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
$lastName=if(isset($_POST['lastN'])){ $lastName=$_POST['lastN']; };
```

as I said in comments, that's incorrect.

Replace your present block with this:

```
$dDate=date("l", (strtotime($_POST['daydate'])));
$mon;
$tue;
$wed;
$thur;
$fri;
$dayVar;
$timeIN=$_POST['inD'];
$timeOUT=$_POST['outD'];

if(isset($_POST['lastN'])){
$lastName=$_POST['lastN'];

echo $lastName;

}

$hoursDay;
$weekID;

// etc.
```

You can also try replacing `isset` with `!empty`

You can also use a ternary operator:

```
$lastName=!empty($_POST['lastN']) ? $_POST['lastN'] : '';
```

rewrite:

```
$dDate=date("l", (strtotime($_POST['daydate'])));
$mon;
$tue;
$wed;
$thur;
$fri;
$dayVar;
$timeIN=$_POST['inD'];
$timeOUT=$_POST['outD'];

echo $lastName=!empty($_POST['lastN']) ? $_POST['lastN'] : '';

$hoursDay;
$weekID;

// etc.
```

you can replace `!empty` with `isset` also.

**Edit:**

You're getting that warning because `echo $lastName;` is outside conditional statements. Place it after `$lastName=$_POST['lastN'];` in the conditional statement.

---

**Edit #2:** - tested example:

I tested the following with success, so I have no idea why you're getting warnings.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
Select Student Name: 
<select id="lastN" name="lastN">
<option value="" selected> Select a Name from the List Below</option>
<option value="Alvarez">Liana Alvarez</option>
<option value="Barlow">Debra Barlow</option>
<option value="Bester">Anthony Bester</option>
<option value="Delvalle">Madelyn Delvalle</option>
<option value="Flowers">Crystal Flowers</option>
<option value="Hoefner">Peggy Hoefner</option>
<option value="Mingo">Kamika Mingo</option>
<option value="Richards">Deyanira Richards</option>
<option value="Sims">Charles Sims</option>
<option value="Wixom">Jason Wixom</option>
<option value="Pittman">Toniqua Pittman </option>
<option value="Mainer">Sandra Mainer</option>
</select>
<br>
Date: <input type="date" name="daydate">
<br>
Time In: <input type="time" name="inD">
Time Out:<input type="time" name="outD">
<br>
Not listed here? <a href="#">Click here to create a new Student.</a>
<br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['lastN'])){
$lastName=$_POST['lastN'];

    echo $lastName;

}

?>
```

- You will then need to fill in the rest.

---

**Edit #3** (last ditch effort)

Here, name your submit button to:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND DATA">
```

Then do: (and being my last ditch effort), being a complete rewrite and run this inside the same file and not seperate files.

Sidenote: You can also change `action="weekAttendance.php"` to `action=""` since it's inside the same file.

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

?>

<form action="weekAttendance.php" method="POST">
Select Student Name: 
<select id="lastN" name="lastN">
<option value="" selected> Select a Name from the List Below</option>
<option value="Alvarez">Liana Alvarez</option>
<option value="Barlow">Debra Barlow</option>
<option value="Bester">Anthony Bester</option>
<option value="Delvalle">Madelyn Delvalle</option>
<option value="Flowers">Crystal Flowers</option>
<option value="Hoefner">Peggy Hoefner</option>
<option value="Mingo">Kamika Mingo</option>
<option value="Richards">Deyanira Richards</option>
<option value="Sims">Charles Sims</option>
<option value="Wixom">Jason Wixom</option>
<option value="Pittman">Toniqua Pittman </option>
<option value="Mainer">Sandra Mainer</option>
</select>
<br>
Date: <input type="date" name="daydate">
<br>
Time In: <input type="time" name="inD">
Time Out:<input type="time" name="outD">
<br>
Not listed here? <a href="#">Click here to create a new Student.</a>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND DATA">
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $dDate=date("l", (strtotime($_POST['daydate'])));
    $mon;
    $tue;
    $wed;
    $thur;
    $fri;
    $dayVar;
    $timeIN=$_POST['inD'];
    $timeOUT=$_POST['outD'];

        if(isset($_POST['lastN'])){
    $lastName=$_POST['lastN'];
    echo $lastName;
    }
    $hoursDay;
    $weekID;
    #$totalHours2= ($mon + $tue + $wed + $thur +$fri)/24)
    if ($dDate==="Monday"){
        $mon="Monday";
        $dayVar=$mon;
    }
    if ($dDate==="Tuesday"){
        $tue="Tue";
        $dayVar=$tue;   
    }
    if ($dDate==="Wednesday"){
        $wed="Wed";
        $dayVar=$wed;
    }
    if ($dDate==="Thursday"){
        $thur="Thurs";
        $dayVar=$thur;

    }
    if ($dDate==="Friday"){
        $fri="Fri";
        $dayVar=$fri;
    }

    /*$sql="INSERT INTO $dayVar ('$dayVar', first_name2, last_name2,wid)
    VALUES($hoursDay','$firstName', '$lastName','$weekId');*/
    echo $dayVar." <strong> Time In</strong> " .$timeIN." <strong>Time Out</strong> " .$timeOUT;
    echo $lastName;

} // brace for if(isset($_POST['submit']))

?>
```

Comment: @motoko96 echo it how and where? this shouldn't be failing.

Comment: At the very end of my original code, you'll see "echo $lastName;", so when I attempt to echo the value from the POST, it doesn't display.

Comment: @motoko96 Ok, I know why you're getting that warning now, it's because `echo $lastName;` is outside conditional statements. Place it after `$lastName=$_POST['lastN'];` I have made an edit to that effect.

Comment: It no longer shows an error however it still does not echo the value :/

Comment: @motoko96 I added an example. Look under **Edit #2: - tested example**. take it from there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance and patience. I'm new to php and I know it shows lol. I'm still trying to get it working but for now I'll change the input from a select to a text. Thanks again.

Comment: @motoko96 you're welcome. However the question still remains unsolved, and that kind of bothers me lol

Comment: Yeah I have no idea why it won't work, I've used a snippet in another form I created and it worked just fine. Seems this form is cursed.

Comment: @motoko96 the thing is, you still have `echo $lastName;` below `echo $dayVar." <strong> Time In</strong>.............` you'll get an undefined variable warning there. Keep in mind, you need a conditional statement to check if any of the inputs have been set/filled. That the variables are also contained inside a conditional statement. When all else fails, split your HTML form in one file, and put the PHP/SQL in a second file. But keep the `echo $lastName;` inside the conditional statement also. That's how you'll get it to work.

Comment: @motoko96 But do as I said there.... remove the `echo $lastName;` from the last line of your code.

Comment: @motoko96 I've made a final ditch effort edit. Reload and look under **Edit #3 (last ditch effort)**. There's really nothing else I can do here, except you buy me a plane ticket and I'll get there in a jiffy ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using procedural PHP, it's probably preferable you put your form submission inside `isset()` function also give you `<input type="submit">` an name attribute, may be "  `name='submit'`  ". 
So you will have

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//do your code here
}
```

Plus make sure there's no other form field with same name.
One last thing but not the least:
Preferable you do a switch case than having multiple if statement.

```
$day = $_POST['day'];

switch($day){
case: "Monday"
$day = "Mon";
break;
//Continue with other days here

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the switch statement feedback, I'll be sure to implement it. I had the same issue where the$lastName variable would not echo.

Comment: Your code is running fine, believe me. I just tested it and I can get all the submitted values well.